# Wordpress: How To Load PHP or OnClick in Posts?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

When I try to load this simple code in my wordpress post,

```
<a href="#" onClick="return AMIdownload(true,'11721','1.1.5.26','.','.','','http://oi61.tinypic.com/167uu0j.jpg','test try','http://bit.ly/1CYaaJs')">Download</a>
```

I inserted the above codes in "text" / "codes" area of the editor,
but when I went over to the Visuals,

it shows "Download", which is fine,
but when I revert back to the "text" area it seems wordpress has strip away the PHP codes, leaving behind only,

```
<a href="#">Download</a>
```

It basically strips away all the onClick php codings,

can any wordpress guru's out there point me in the right direction?
I've tried some PHP loading plugins but it seems that it won't work?

Thanks

Comment: There's no PHP in your code above. Also, you can't put PHP in the WYSIWYG editor of wordpress.

Comment: if you want to insert php code into a wordpress post, you need to use a `shortcode`. But again, it doesn't look like you have any PHP in your example, since you have no `<?php` and  `?>` tags

Comment: is `AMIdownload` supposed to be a `javascript` function? You can't assign a `php` function to an `onclick` event

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run a PHP function from an anchor href link:

The link passes the var "dl" with a value of "1" in the query string back to the same page.

```
<a href="./?dl=1">
```

When the "dl" is received, the function is run.

```
if (intval($_GET['dl'])==1)
```

Assumes the page is index.php

```
<?php
if (intval($_GET['dl'])==1){AMIdownload(true,'11721','1.1.5.26','.','.','','http://oi61.tinypic.com/167uu0j.jpg','test try','http://bit.ly/1CYaaJs');}
echo <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Call PHP</title><body>
<a href="./?dl=1">Download</a>
</body></html>
EOT;
function AMIdownload(){
  echo "<h2>Downloading</h2>";
}
?>
```